# How to Randomize the button location in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, word-cloud

I am trying to create a clickable word cloud for which I am starting to apply logic with button. I am able to split the words of text file using regular expressions and create button for each word. But each button's position is shown in a column view. like in the image below:

[image]

Does tkinter have any function to randomize this location and alter the buttons manually that can give me a look of a clikable word cloud.

Here's my working solution:

```
# import the 'tkinter' module
import tkinter
# import regular expression
import re

# create a new window
window = tkinter.Tk()
# set the window title
window.title("Commands")
# set the window icon
window.wm_icon

bitmap('Icon.ico')

# initially, the button hasn't been pressed
presses = 0


# a function that changes the text of the label to a location of the word clicked
def locate():
    global presses
    # add code to find the location of the word ---------------
    # update the label text with the new value of 'presses' -----------
    lbl.configure(text=presses)

# create a label to display a message
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text=presses)
lbl.pack()

# looping through the number f words
# create a new button, assign a specific text to each button and provide an argument called 'command'
# which in this case calls a function called 'callback'
with open ('sample.txt','r') as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    # Removing URLs
    f_contents = re.sub(r'http\S+',"",f_contents)
    # Removing all the punctuations
    f_contents = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', f_contents)
    for word in f_contents.split():
        btn = tkinter.Button(window, text=word, command=locate)
        btn.pack()

# draw the window, and start the 'application'
window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `place` geometry manager to put widgets at precise coordinates. You can use `random.randint` to compute a random coordinate. If you use a canvas, you can use the built-in method `find_overlapping` to determine if anything would overlap the computed placement.

Here's a quick example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]

def place_label(canvas, label):
    '''place a label on a canvas in a random, non-overlapping location'''
    width = label.winfo_reqwidth()
    height = label.winfo_reqheight()

    tries = 0
    while True and tries < 1000:
        tries += 1 # failsafe, to prevent an infinite loop
        x = random.randint(0, 200-width)
        y = random.randint(0, 200-height)
        items = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x+width, y+height)
        if len(items) == 0:
            canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label, anchor="nw")
            break

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for word in words:
    label = tk.Label(root, text=word)
    place_label(canvas, label)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The logic fits perfectly, can you recommend a way to avoid overlapping of words?

Comment: @NikulVyas: I don't know what you mean. This code includes avoiding overlapping of words.

Comment: I don't see all the words in the canvas every time from my data source I thought its overlapping may be if I increase the length of the canvas it will show all words.

Comment: @NikulVyas: if the code can't find a place to put the label after 1000 attempts, it will simply ignore that label and try the next. You need to put  your own logic in that code. This isn't a _solution_, it's an _illustration of the technique_

Comment: I am implementing a different logic through your guidance above. Its working now I just forgot to add the fill & expand logic in the canvas.pack function. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but after removing .pack() from your code to use .grid(), I used numpy to generate random numbers to place the buttons randomly.

```
import numpy as np
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    # Removing URLs
    f_contents = re.sub(r'http\S+', "", f_contents)
    # Removing all the punctuations
    f_contents = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', f_contents)
    for word in f_contents.split():
        btn = tkinter.Button(window, text=word, command=locate).grid(row=int(np.random.normal(len(f_contents)/2,1)),column=int(np.random.normal(len(f_contents)/2,1)))
```

I used normal random to make it look like a word cloud.